# Android TableLayout Wrap Text issues

Tags: android, textview, android-tablelayout

My tablelayout displays a bunch of values that are random and is created programatically.

The issue I am having is that because I don't know the content that'll be displayed on the table I am not able to use setColumnShrinkable(index, true) and therefore since the table is big, some of the columns would get cut off and not show.

I've tried playing with `mTableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);` but that would result in columns that shouldn't shrink to shrink and thereby making the wrapping of the texts formatted poorly (see image below) and also the height of each column is too large.

I've also tried playing with minWidth of the columns but that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

What would be the best wayt to tackle this issue? Thanks!

[image]